# Как исправить эту ошибку java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, файлы

Я хочу прочитать файл и если там email существует - ничего не делать, а если не существует - записать email в файл.

```
private void readEmail(String file, Email emails) {
    try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
        Email email;
        while ((email = (Email) objectInputStream.readObject()) == null || (email = (Email) objectInputStream.readObject()) != null) {
            if (!emails.getEmail().equals(email)) {
                writeInFile(file, emails);
            } else {
                System.out.println("User already exist!");
            }
        }
        objectInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Измените метод так, чтобы он занимался именно тем, чем он должен заниматься, а именно - читать. Другой должен проверять, третий - писать. Ошибки скорее всего уйдут сами собой.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, метод `readObject` не возвращает `null` в конце файла. Он выбрасывает исключение `EOFException`, когда достигнут конец файла.
Ловите данное исключение и обрабатывайте его необходимым образом.

Во-вторых, вот здесь `while ((email = (Email) objectInputStream.readObject()) == null || (email = (Email) objectInputStream.readObject()) != null)` Вы выполняете что-то не совсем понятное. Как минимум, вы дважды вызываете метод `readObject`, читаете сразу два объекта из файла, переопределяете `email` и, как следствие, после обрабатываете лишь второй объект, теряя первый.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить проверку в `while`

```
objectInputStream.available() > 0
```